# reference of anchor within Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

how can I get a reference of an anchor tag within an Iframe? How is this done with Mootools or  without using any library?

```
<iframe id="myIframe" class="myclass" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 55px;
    height: 20px;">

        <body>
            <a id="btn" tabindex="1" href="http://www.vk.nl">
        </body>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any library, you should use:

```
var framwWindow = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow;
var anchor = frameWindow.document.getElementById('btn');
```

Note: You cannot include a page in an iframe in the way as shown at the question. This will work:

Main:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="frame.html"></iframe>
```

`frame.html`:

```
<a id="btn" href="...">Link</a>
```